# How to add code behind manually on asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a website on the IIS but it has only the aspx file. Now I need to add the code behind for some pages. How do I go about this?

I've been trying to add the attribute "codebehind" and "autoeventwireup" on the top of the aspx file but no luck (the page_load event is not being called). Also, if I double click on the button from the design view in Visual Studio, it creates the javascript handle (not the server code).

Comment: How was this site created? File->New Web Site, or File->New Project? Also, which version of Visual Studio are you using, and which version of .NET?

Answer (score 1):

In your page directive on the aspx page (`<%@ Page...`), you need two pieces:

```
1) CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" 
2) Inherits="_Default"
```

In your code-behind file, you need two things:

```
1) The file name has to be whatever you specified above (CodeFile = "...)
2) the class name has to be whatever you specified above (Inherits="_...)
```

For example, if your aspx page was named "default.aspx" then your page direction in the aspx page would look similar to this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

And your code-behind would look similar to this:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

Comment: two thoughts: 1) did you spell it right?  (remember the underscore in both places).  2) there might be something going on behind the scenes...  to handle that, you can create an aspx page from scratch through visual studio, and it will automaticalyl create a code-behind page for you that's properly setup.  At that point, just copy/paste your markup from the original aspx page into the new one, and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

you want the `@page` directive and the class attribute. [MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx)